# How to connect monitor USB to computer wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

I have a Dell U2713hm which comes with USB 3.0 ports. My desktop box is around 15 meters away from the monitor. I managed to connect the two via very long DisplayPort cable, but I cannot find a USB 3.0 cable which is that long. So, is there a way to establish the connection between the monitor and the desktop so that I can use my USB ports on the monitor? I was thinking wireless, but if you also know of another method, e.g. via Ethernet cable, please share how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the USB ports, then the USB cable from the monitor to the PC MUST be used.  The maximum cable length is dependent on the make-up of the cable in question, but 3 meters (9.8 feet) seems to be the max without the use of a USB hub.  If you want to extend the display to 15 feet, you likely will be required to use a USB hub and an extension cable.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB for specs.

There ARE longer USB extension cables and they WILL work to supply power, however the ability to function normally will likely be impractical.

[USB 3.0 Extension cables on NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100016767%20600020303%20600020224&IsNodeId=1&Description=usb%203.0%20extension&name=16%20-%2020%20ft.&Order=BESTMATCH)